# Acquire permissions to retrieve user profile info

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-account, google-profiles-api

I have this call (I removed error-handling for brevity's sake):

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function (token) {

 let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
    req.onload = function() {
      console.log('this userinfo => ', req.response);
    };
    req.send();  

});
```

I get this logged:

```
this userinfo =>  {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

I believe that I need to add the following to my manifest.json file...

before I have this:

```
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "5461307462-7gebv03xxx9csfidfg5f6ggxxxrju9374.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },
```

then I add this:

```
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "5461307462-7gebv03xxx9csfidfg5f6ggxxxrju9374.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo.picture",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },
```

**the problem though, is that the authentication method then changes. I no longer get this view:**

[image]

**instead I get a new Chrome tab that looks like this:**

[image]

**the problem is**, no matter how many times I login, it always bounces back to the same login tab. Furthermore, I cannot access any other Chrome tab, it keeps bouncing me back to the same Chrome auth tab. It's so weird and such an awful experience.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Did you enable all the related APIs for your project in Google APIs Console? Were you signed into Google Chrome before calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`?

Comment: @IvánNokonoko perhaps I need to enable those APIs? Do you know how to do that? I am not signed in before calling `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()`, to my knowlege.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the problem is that the **scopes** you request have invalid addresses (where did you get them from?)

Try changing:
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`

by: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and/or `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

Maybe the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo` works as well.

You can also check the useful [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer).

Comment: thanks, do you know what Google API I might need to enable in the Google Developer Console?

Comment: I see about 50 potential APIs to enable, but I can't figure out which API might pertain to my issue.

Comment: @AlexanderMills  Maybe you don't need to enable any API for the scopes you use. Try with the correct scope address first.

Comment: Hi Ivan, using this in scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo`, gave me the exact same problem. Super annoying. Also I cannot figure out which Google API to enable in the Google Developers Console.

Comment: Ok so, this works in scopes `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`, but this didn't work `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo`. It looks like it's using OAuth instead of OAuth2?